# Fastest high precision average of a list in python3

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, average

What is the fastest way to calculate the average of a list in the precision that a `float` type would allow. I know about `numpy.average` but that in trunkates a few digits off, compared to how many digits a `float` type would allow. So I am looking for a fast way to calculate the average of a big list of float numbers and give it's average in floats in Python 3.

I have this function so far:

```
def average(inp_array):
    return (sum(inp_array) / float(len(inp_array)))
```

Is there anything faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need weight for averaging the data, you can use [`numpy.mean`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) with `dtype` parameter.

```
>>> np.mean(np.random.random_sample(100), dtype=np.float128)
0.49566869596595826807
```

If you put `np.float64` or `np.float32` you will get lower precision:

```
>>> np.mean(np.random.random_sample(100), dtype=np.float64)
0.4827266837646129
>>> np.mean(np.random.random_sample(100), dtype=np.float32)
0.5099036
```